# PyQt - Manually resizing menu widget does not resize its content

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

I am using a QToolButton to open up a menu, which is a simple QWidget. Inside this widget live a QTextEdit and a Button. At the lower right corner there is a QSizeGrip which I want to use to let the user resize the widget and thus the QTextEdit.

If I use this widget on its own inside a MainWindow *(Option1)* everything works as expected. If however I put this widget into the menu *(Option2)*, I cannot resize it anymore. Dragging the QSizeGrip changes the size of the Menu but not the Widget. I have already experimented with `setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.SubWindow)` and `setSizePolicy(..)` without any notable effect.

My Question is: How do I make the widget (together with the TextEdit) resizable?

Here is the code and below a picture.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
        self.TextEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()

        self.Button = QtGui.QPushButton("Push")

        self.UpdateWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.UpdateWidget.setLayout(QtGui.QHBoxLayout())
        self.UpdateWidget.layout().addWidget(self.Button, 1)
        self.UpdateWidget.layout().addWidget(QtGui.QSizeGrip(self), 0)

        self.layout().addWidget(self.TextEdit)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.UpdateWidget)

        self.layout().setSpacing(0)
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.UpdateWidget.layout().setSpacing(4)
        self.UpdateWidget.layout().setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        # This is what I already tried to make the menu resizable:
        #self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.SubWindow)
        #self.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        #self.TextEdit.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.SubWindow)
        #self.TextEdit.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)


class ToolBar(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ToolBar, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QHBoxLayout())
        self.Button = QtGui.QToolButton()
        self.Button.setText("Open Text Editor")
        self.Button.setPopupMode(QtGui.QToolButton.InstantPopup)
        self.Button.setMenu(QtGui.QMenu(self.Button))
        action = QtGui.QWidgetAction(self.Button)
        action.setDefaultWidget(MyWidget())
        self.Button.menu().addAction(action)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.Button)


class App(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(App, self).__init__(parent)

        #Option 1: 
        #Use MyWidget in MainWindow. This works as expected.
        #self.central = MyWidget()

        #Option 2:
        #Use MyWidget as default widgt for a menu action. 
        #In this case MyWidget cannot be resized.
        self.central = ToolBar()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.central)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    thisapp = App()
    thisapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is because `Button.menu` doesn't inform your widget about size change.

In ToolBar you can assign own function to `resizeEvent` which will resize your widget.

You need access to your widget

```
    self.MyW = MyWidget()
```

and you can assign own function

```
    self.Button.menu().resizeEvent = self.onResize

def onResize(self, event):        
    self.MyW.resize(event.size())
```

Full code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)    
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())

        self.TextEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()

        self.Button = QtGui.QPushButton("Push")

        self.UpdateWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.UpdateWidget.setLayout(QtGui.QHBoxLayout())
        self.UpdateWidget.layout().addWidget(self.Button, 1)
        self.UpdateWidget.layout().addWidget(QtGui.QSizeGrip(self), 0)

        self.layout().addWidget(self.TextEdit)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.UpdateWidget)

        self.layout().setSpacing(0)
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.UpdateWidget.layout().setSpacing(4)
        self.UpdateWidget.layout().setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)


class ToolBar(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ToolBar, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QHBoxLayout())

        self.Button = QtGui.QToolButton()
        self.Button.setText("Open Text Editor")
        self.Button.setPopupMode(QtGui.QToolButton.InstantPopup)
        self.Button.setMenu(QtGui.QMenu(self.Button))

        self.MyW = MyWidget() # <-- here
        action = QtGui.QWidgetAction(self.Button) 
        action.setDefaultWidget(self.MyW) # <-- here

        self.Button.menu().addAction(action)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.Button)

        self.Button.menu().resizeEvent = self.onResize # <-- here

    def onResize(self, event):        # <-- here
        self.MyW.resize(event.size()) # <-- here

class App(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(App, self).__init__(parent)

        #Option 1: 
        #Use MyWidget in MainWindow. This works as expected.
        #self.central = MyWidget()

        #Option 2:
        #Use MyWidget as default widgt for a menu action. 
        #In this case MyWidget cannot be resized.
        self.central = ToolBar()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.central)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    thisapp = App()
    thisapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Maybe it can be done olny with `SizeGrip` and `MyWidget` but I didn't try