# Why do some widgets not stretch to fill the maximum space in a layout?

Tags: python, pyqt

When I create a QGridLayout, and I add a couple of widgets to it, some of the widgets do not stretch to fill the section of the layout that contains it.

```
class Grid(QGridLayout):
    def __init__(self, grid_widget):
        arrow = QPixmap("icons/arrow.png") #initial image is facing up
        self.arrows = []
        locs = [(0,1),
                (0,2),
                (1,2),
                (2,2),
                (2,1),
                (2,0),
                (1,0),
                (0,0)]

        for rot in range(len(locs)):
            transform = QTransform().rotate(45*rot)
            icon = arrow.transformed(transform, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            self.arrows.append(ExpandButton(icon, rot, grid_widget)) #ExpandButton inherits from QPushButton

        for i, loc in enumerate(locs):
            self.addWidget(self.arrows[i], loc[0], loc[1])
    
        self.addWidget(grid_widget, 1, 1)
```

[image: Result]

As you can see, the QPushButtons on the sides to not stretch to fill the layout like the QPushButtons at the top. Is there any way to fix this so that the QPushButtons at the sides stretch vertically to fill the layout, like how the ones at the top stretch horizontally to fill the layout there?

Comment: `button.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)` ?

Comment: @furas That solution works, thank you! Could you post that below so I can accept it? I had tried to do that before, when I didn't have the buttons as their own class, and it didn't work, so I never bothered to try it again.

Comment: @furas Also, do you know why widgets do not automatically fill up the maximum space?

Comment: @JonathanLiu Just look at the default sizePolicy of them. It isn't the same for each widget. See for example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I know buttons (as default) expand only horizontally - everybody expect low buttons.

You have to set vertical and horizontal expanding.

```
button.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136655/pyqt-manually-resizing-menu-widget-does-not-resize-its-content). Any idea why?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Qt has visual GUI builders like [Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html) and [Qt Creator](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/index.html) which lets you build and test GUI - it is created for C++ code, not Python, but still you can test different properties (size policy, expand,etc.) and then use this information in Python code.